# Running all bound instances of a goal on the command line

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a bunch of SQL commands bound to the `pre-integration-test` phase whose job is to create a "test" database and point the application to it.

Sometimes, I want to just "rebuild" my test database without all the other stuff in the lifecycle.  For example, if my test is catastrophically failing and screwing up the test database, I may have to rebuild it several times until I figure out what the problem is.

Here's what my POM looks like:

```
<profile>
    <id>test-setup-teardown</id>
       <activation>
           <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
       </activation>
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>${database-dependency-groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${database-dependency-artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <version>${database-dependency-version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <configuration>
                        <url>${test-database-admin-url}</url>
                        <username>${test-database-admin-username}</username>
                        <password>${test-database-admin-password}</password>
                        <driver>${database-driver}</driver>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                    </configuration>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test-database-pre-setup</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sqlCommand>${test-database-teardown}</sqlCommand>
                                <onError>continue</onError>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>test-database-setup</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sqlCommand>${test-database-setup}</sqlCommand>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>test-database-schema</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <url>${test-database-url}</url>
                                <username>${database-user}</username>
                                <password>${database-password}</password>
                                <srcFiles>
                                    <srcFile>${basedir}/metadata/build/database/${database-engine}/appx.sql</srcFile>
                                </srcFiles>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>test-database-teardown</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sqlCommand>${test-database-teardown}</sqlCommand>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

How can I run all the executions of this profile?  Something like mvn `sql:execute` only runs one of the executions (the last, I think).

I've tried making the bound phase be a property, and then allow the user to specify another profile which changes the default from `pre-integration-test` to `validate`, but explaining to someone why rebuilds are executed thusly:

```
mvn validate -Pforce-rebuild,test-setup-teardown
```

simply enforces the fact that non-toy projects have a lot of magic in the POM.  Please, show me the way!

<ed>Maybe a good solution would be a way to run executions by id from the command line?</ed>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe a good solution would be a way to run executions by id from the command line?

This is not possible. Executions are for binding to the lifecycle.

And calling `sql:execute` and passing all the parameters on the command line doesn't seem to be a viable option (this could have been done in a batch script but there will be a problem with the `srcFiles` optional parameter anyway).

So, in my opinion, the "less worse" option would be to duplicate (sigh) the `sql-maven-plugin` setup in another profile, for example *`rebuild`*, to bind the desired executions on the `validate` phase and to declare the `validate` goal as default goal in this profile. This would allow to type something like this:

```
mvn -Prebuild
```

Maybe some optimizations are possible to avoid duplication (by variablelizing the execution phase like you did) but this means more black magic to me (which might not be desirable).

Comment: Good call on the default goal.  I don't like the duplication either, but agree that it's probably the least-bad solutions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"pre-integration-test" is a phase you can invoke directly.

```
mvn -Ptest-setup-teardown pre-integration-test
```

This will still go through the lifecycle of compile, copy-resources, unit tests, etc. You could try to add `-DskipTests=true` to the command (not sure if this will skip integration-test phase too):

```
mvn -Ptest-setup-teardown pre-integration-test -DskipTests=true
```

Comment: I'm specifically trying to avoid going through the lifecycle as it takes 3-4 minutes to get to pre-integration-test.  I've tried adding all the plug-ins to profiles so they may be easily turned off, but this adds a lot of complication when trying to have branching behaviour (i.e. sometimes do this, sometimes do that, etc.).

Comment: this kind of sounds like the type of task which is best done outside of maven, since it really doesn't have much to do with building your main app